# Update statment mysql php row in database

Tags: php, android, mysql, base-de-datos, update

Por favor me podrian ayudar cual es el error en el siguiente codigo php para actualizar un registro donde se toma el correo del registro en la base de datos...al ejecutarla me salta al error automatico "noActualiza". agradezco su ayuda para que se ejecute la sentencia correctamente y tome "actualiza".
aqui esta el codigo de mi script:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost="mysql.webcindario.com";
$database_localhost="android";
$username_localhost="android";
$password_localhost="0000";

$conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $correo = $_POST["correo"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
    $clave = $_POST["clave"];
    $ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];


    $sql="UPDATE registro SET nombre_apellido= ? , correo= ?, telefono=?, direccion=?, clave=? , ciudad=? WHERE correo=?";
    $stm=$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bind_param('ssssi',$nombre,$correo,$telefono,$direccion,$clave,$ciudad);

    if($stm->execute()){
        echo "actualiza";
    }else{
        echo "noActualiza";
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, esta es la versión en español de stack over flow

Comment: ya realice la traduccion

Comment: veo que cuando indicas los tipos de valores, ciudad lo estas declarando como integer, no debería ser s de string y clave debería ser integer? checa bien que se correspondan todos los tipos de datos por que por lo demás lo veo correcto

Comment: sigue sin funcionar ya declare todo como string s y nada

Comment: añade por favor a tu pregunta el tipo de dato para cada columna

Comment: listo ya lo hice...

Comment: añade esto a tu línea que dice no actualiza haber que resultado te devuelve echo "noActualiza".mysqli_errno();

Comment: En tu `bind_param('ssssi',...` debería ser `bind_param('ssssss',...` , si ya lo tienes cambiado actualiza tu pregunta con los cambios. En tu código tienes 4 s y 1 i, deberían ser 6 s, una por cada variable tipo string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en tu consulta SQL y en la utilización de `bind_param`

Vemos primero la consulta:

```
$sql="UPDATE registro SET nombre_apellido= ? , correo= ?, telefono=?, direccion=?, clave=? , ciudad=? WHERE correo=?";
```

Tenemos 7 marcadores (?) :

```
1    nombre_apellido= ? , 
2    correo= ?, 
3    telefono=?, 
4    direccion=?, 
5    clave=? , 
6    ciudad=? WHERE 
7    correo=?
```

Por lo que la consulta para ejecutarse correctamente esperará 7 parámetros para ejecutarse correctamente que asignaremos mediante `bind_param`.

Revisemos pues el `bind_param`

```
$stm->bind_param('ssssi',$nombre,$correo,$telefono,$direccion,$clave,$ciudad);
```

`bind_param` recibe un primer parámetro que será un String indicando el tipo del dato que será asignado al marcador de izquierda a derecha y después recibe como se haya indicado en primero y en la consulta preparada.

Lo primero que vemos es que el número de tipos es incorrecto `$stm->bind_param('ssssi', ...)` solo estas pasando 5 tipos en el String cuando en la consulta tienes declarados 7 parámetros con `?`.

En cuanto a los datos (variables) que pasas a `bind_param` solo estas pasando 6 de las 7 que se esperarían.

Resumiemdo debería quedar asi:

```
$sql="UPDATE registro SET nombre_apellido= ? , correo= ?, telefono=?, direccion=?, clave=? , ciudad=? WHERE correo=?";
$stm=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$stm->bind_param('sssssss', $nombre, $correo, $telefono, $direccion, $clave, $ciudad, $correo);
```

Utilizamos 7 `s` para indicar los tipos de los 7 parámetros ya que según la imagen que pones son todos de tipo `varchar` y a continuación pasamos las 7 variables, en este caso 2 veces la variable `$correo`, siguiendo el orden de los marcadores.